# Load condition within execution line in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, conditional-statements

I want to execute a command with an option that depends on the attribution of a variable. If the variable is set, load the option with the value, but if not, don't load that option. This is what I have:

```
if [ -n "$variable" ]
  then command ... -option $variable
  else command ...
fi
```

The idea would be to merge this into a single command with the condition within so that I don't have to repeat the other options of the command two times.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I have a simpler solution than the one you accepted, pls take a look at it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bash arrays:

```
opts=()
[ "$variable" ] && opts+=(-option "$variable")
command ... "${opts[@]}"
```

Because this uses bash arrays, this will work even if `$variable` contains whitespace or other difficult characters.

#### How it works

- `opts=()`

  This creates an empty array called `opts`.
- `[ "$variable" ] && opts+=(-option "$variable")`

  If `$variable` is not empty, then we append `-option` and `$variable` to the array `opts`.
- `command ... "${opts[@]}"`

  This executes your command.  If `opts` is non-empty, then its elements are added to the command.  If `opts` is empty, nothing is added: it would be as if `"${opts[@]}"` was not there at all.

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm. Just for curiosity, what does the "@" stands for?

Comment: @Juan Glad it worked for you.  The `@` in `${opts[@]}` tells bash to expand each element of `opts` to a separate word.

Answer (score 0):

Then take your command and make it a function like so:

```
function command_function () {
  command ... -option $variable
}

if [ -n "$variable" ]
  then command_function ... -option $variable
  else command_function ...
fi
```

Just so you know the parentheses in the Bash function don’t pass anything.

Answer (score 0):

Using *Bash* substitution ([Shell-Parameter-Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)) for a concise, still readable syntax:

```
$ echo ${variable:+-option $variable}

$ variable=yes
$ echo ${variable:+-option $variable}
-option yes
```

Answer (score 0):

The following one-liner will do:

```
[ x"$VARIABLE" = x ] && echo UNSET || echo SET
```

This tests whether the variable *x"$VARIABLE"* equals *x*, in other words if *$VARIABLE* is empty; if the test is satisfied the first option (*echo UNSET*) is executed, if the test is **not** satisfied the last option is executed (*echo SET*). If you do not wish to do anything in the second case, you can do

```
[ x"$VARIABLE" = x ] && echo UNSET || :
```

This is considerably simpler than the other solutions, allows the evaluation of the condition only once, is robust against strange characters appearing in VARIABLE.